# "\r\n" not working when viewing file on Windows Notepad

Tags: php

When i tried to write a file with \r\n using fwrite in PHP it works in Notepad++ but when i tried to view my file in Notepad it did not detect the new line. Here is my code.

```
$log = "[".date_format($date,'Y/m/d')."-".$sampleVariable."]".$sampleVariable."/".$terminal."/".
                            $sampleVariable."/".$result."/".$sampleVariable;

fwrite($filepointer, $log."\r\n");
```

I also tried PHP_EOL but it is still the same.

Comment: Did you try 'fwrite($filepointer, $log.PHP_EOL);' ?

Comment: Yes i also tried it, but it is still the same.

Comment: Check if there isn't a mix of "/r/n" , "\r" or "\n" - I've noticed Notepad gets confused with it.

Comment: I already tried "\r" alone and "\n" alone but it still the same.